# What knob in Windows can I turn to permit a user to create local groups?

Tags: windows, security, groups

I am aware that I can make a user an administrator on the local windows server and that user can then create local users and local groups.  However, what if I want to only give a user the ability to create local groups?  Is there a knob I can turn to delegate this capability without giving the user full administrator abilities?

Comment: The Power User group used to have rights to create local groups and users in Windows pre-Vista. Lets dig around and see if we can find the relevant bits from the security template.

Comment: Have you explored policy options?

Comment: I have done some digging under User Rights Assignments and nothing obvious showed up for me.  However, I must confess that I do not know what some of them mean like "Replace a process level token" and other rights with cryptic names.  I am not sure precisely what is meant by "security template" and "policy options" so please take me to school a bit further if you like.